# How to create a storybook arg that selects amongst a list of React Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components, storybook

One of my components, say a card component, takes an icon component as a child.
This icon component is selected from a fixed list of Icon componnents. I want to be able to create a select control type in the storybook page for the Card component such that I can choose a fixed icon from the list and display them in the Card.

Shape of  component:

```html
<Card>
  {icon}
  <Styled.Title>{title}</Styled.Title>
  <Styled.Description> {description} </Styled.Description>
  <Styled.TextLink href="{href}" onClick="{onClick}"> {label} </Styled.TextLink>
</Card>
```

`icon` here is a React component.

The Storybook file for `<Card />` looks something like this:

```js
const CardTemplate: Story<CardProps> = (args) => <Card {...args} />

export default {
  title: 'Display/Card',
  component: Card,
  args: {
    title: 'fluff',
    description:
      'some description',
  },
  argTypes: {
    icon: {
      defaultValue: null,
      options: [] // How do I make this an array of objects: {label: key, value: value},
      control: {
        type: 'select',
      },
    },
  },
} as Meta
```

In another file I am exporting an object which contains the names and values of each Icon react component:

```js
export const IconsList = {
  Icon1: <Icon1 />,
  Icon2: <Icon2 />,
  Icon3: <Icon3 />,
}
```

How do I ensure that people can switch betweeen these components in the `icon` arg in the storybook page for `<Card />` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are at the correct way, but you missed a couple of things.
I think that the following snipet will work for you.

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Icon1, Icon2, Icon3 } from "./IconList";

const ICONS = { Icon1, Icon2, Icon3 }

const meta: Meta<typeof Card> = {
  title: 'Display/Card',
  component: Card,
  args: {
    title: 'fluff',
    description:
      'some description',
  },
  argTypes: {
    icon: {
      control: 'select', // or "radio",
      options: Object.keys(ICONS),
      defaultValue: null
    },
  },
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Card>;

const CardTemplate = (args: CardProps) => {
    const icon = ICONS[args.icon as keyof typeof ICONS];
    return <Card {...args} icon={icon}>
}

export const CardStory: Story = {
   name: "Card",
   render: (args) => <CardTemplate {...args} />
}
```